# Mongo c# Driver Query (Select subfields)

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

folowing situation:
I have a list of Users, evry one have a field with a List of Comments.

```
User1: {
      ...
      Id : 'xxxx',
      Comment : [{
                   ...
                   Status : 1
                }
                ,{
                   ...
                   Status : 0
                }]
}
```

I am looking for a Mongo c# Query that select all Comments with status 1 of all users in the DB Collection.

sry for bad English.

thx

Comment: You can't do that in MongoDB directly. It doesn't support returning only matching array elements. It's either only the first match, or all. You'd need to do a filter on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx.

I slove it like this:

```
var query1  =  Query.EQ("Comments.Status", 1)
IEnumerable<Comment> comments = Collection.Distinct<Comment>("Comments", query1).Where(x => x.Status == 1);

comments .toList() // <= list of Comments with Status 1
```

if someone has a better solution please post it.

Thx again,

Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have the following classes that contain the serialized values for your collection:

```
public class User1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Comment[] Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
   public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then the query should be something like:

```
var query =
    collection.AsQueryable<User1>().SelectMany(user => user.Comments.Where(com=>com.Status == 1));
```

Comment: That won't work. `SelectMany` isn't supported in MongoDB's Official LINQ implementation.